# Placing a font awesome icon onto an image in a specific place

Tags: html

I want to display a font icon onto an image in a specified place and on hover, display certain data.

I want to print the icon `fa-info-circle` onto an image and I want it to be white, and when hovered on, a message box fades in displaying information.

http://serverlauncherplus.co.uk/maths

I want to display many of these icons in various places on the map image.

My current code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF=8">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <nav>
        </nav>
        <section id="map" class="">
            <div class="container">
                <header>
                    <h2 class="space">Map</h2>
                </header>
                <div class="mapImage">
                    <img src="mapImg.jpg" alt="map" >
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span></a> <!-- NEED THIS ON THE IMAGE MULTIPLE TIMES AND MULTIPLE PLACES -->
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" style="color:white"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute positioning. Simply put, if you try this CSS:

```
.mapImage {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; /*Just for example, so this div is the same size as the image */
}

.pin {
    position: absolute; /* Takes this element out the document flow */
    z-index:10; /* Just in case of z-index issues, remove if not needed */
}

.pin1 {
    left: 50px; /* Move pin1 50px left */
    top: 100px; /* Move pin1 100px down */
}

.pin2 {
    left: 350px; /* Move pin2 350px left */
    top: 30px; /* Move pin2 30px down */
}
```

Then this HTML:

```
<div class="mapImage">
    <img src="mapImg.jpg" alt="map" >
    <a class="pin pin1" href="#"><span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span></a>
    <a class="pin pin2" href="#"><span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span></a>
</div>
```

The `.pin` declaration is there so you don't add position absolute on individual declarations. Then all you need to do is change the left and top (or right and bottom) properties to position your markers.

This is all just for the icon - for the message to popup on hover, give it a go and see how you get on. If you need help, let me know.

Read up on this if you don't understand it (It'll help with the popup message), or ask here and I'll be happy to help :)

http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Good luck buddy!

**EDIT:** I even created a CodePen for you :) http://codepen.io/AshboDev/pen/OXgEQZ

Comment: Thankyou! That is exactly what I needed :) as for the hovering on the icons, I have used the code from this: http://jsfiddle.net/eypm4v5u/ and my code is here: (html) http://prntscr.com/bp540c and the css: http://prntscr.com/bp548z But it doesn't seem to be working, any ideas?

Comment: Glad that's sorted! If you post a link to a fiddle or pen, with the code so the problem is there, I'll take a look for you :)

Comment: I have decided to use a popup message and I got it working, but for some odd reason it has made my entire nav panel and fonts smaller? serverlauncherplus.co.uk/maths My code is here, sorry i couldn't get my code to work on JsFiddle: http://pastebin.com/9SEmsYMh

Comment: Well done! As for the nav issue I've had a quick look at the site. The font size of `#nav ul li a span` in `main.css` line 2064 is 0.8em. The `font-size` on the `body` tag is 14px so 14*0.8 = 11.2px - this is your font size :) If you increase the font size on the `body` to 16px, the nav font size goes up. You have to choices here. Increase the font size on the `body`, or set the font size to a pixel value. If you change the font size on the body, be aware the if other em values are relying on it, it might cause issues. See: https://www.sitepoint.com/power-em-units-css/ (out of characters!) GL!

Comment: Don't know if you're still following this, but I've just checked your link. You need to add `z-index: 50;` to the `.overlay` declaration to stop the pins overlapping the modal :)